# How to reload contents into a datatable inside a dialog in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to JSF so ignore the coding abnormalities

When the search button is clicked in the dialog component the datatable has to reload. But when I tried to do the same, the table contents are not reflected.

```
            <p:fieldset legend="SearchServices">
                <h:panelGrid columns="6" style="margin-bottom:10px;font-size : 9pt">

                    <h:outputLabel for="ServiceName" value="ServiceName" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="serviceModule" value="ServiceModule" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="ServiceGroup" value="ServiceGroup" />
                        <h:outputLabel value="" />
                    <p:inputText id="serviceName" value="#{serviceBeandata.serviceName}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{serviceBeandata.serviceModule}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Manual entry" itemValue="Manualentry" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="sfi files" itemValue="sfifiles" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="liquidify management" itemValue="liquidifymanagement" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{serviceBeandata.serviceGroup}">

                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="None" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="payment" itemValue="payment" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Balance statements" itemValue="Balance statements" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="instruments" itemValue="instruments" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />



                    <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{serviceBeandata.searchacc()}"></p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Reset"></p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
```

I have tried various attributes along with the  but I was never able to get the result. Please do feel free to point out the various errors that may persist in the displayed code.

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="6">
                <p:dataTable id="services"  border="1" value="#{serviceBeandata.searchacc()}" selection="#{serviceBeandata.serviceBeandatas}"  selectionMode="multiple"
                var="Service" liveScroll="true" scrollable="true"  rowKey="#{Service.serviceName}"          
                        scrollHeight="150" scrollRows="20" emptyMessage="" >
                    <p:column headerText="ServiceName" width="200" >
                        <h:outputText value=" #{Service.serviceName}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText=" Servicemodule" width="200">
                        <h:outputText value=" #{Service.serviceModule}" />
                    </p:column>



                    <p:column headerText="Servicegroup" width="350">

                        <h:outputText value="  #{Service.serviceGroup}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellpadding="50">
                <p:commandButton value="AddSelected" action="#{serviceBeandata.loadServiceList}"  style="font-size : 9pt"></p:commandButton>
                <h:outputLabel value="" />
                <h:outputLabel value="" />

                <h:outputLabel value="" />
                <h:outputLabel value="" />
                <p:commandButton value="close" onclick="dlg1.hide()"
                    style="font-size : 9pt"></p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>

    </p:dialog>
```

It maybe worth noting that the table is displayed in an arraylist and the selection attribute used is an array of objects.

The code for the selection attribute within the datatable.

```
public ServiceBeandata[] getServiceBeandatas() {
    return serviceBeandatas;
}

public void setServiceBeandatas(ServiceBeandata[] serviceBeandatas) {
    this.serviceBeandatas = serviceBeandatas;
}
```

The code for loading values into the table (the code triggered for the value attribute in the datatable)

```
public ArrayList<ServiceBeandata> searchacc() {
    System.out.println("entered into the searchaccc");
    Servicedao serv = new Servicedao();
    /* serv_list = serv.getServiceList(); */
    serv_list = serv.search(this);
    return serv_list;
}
```

where

```
 public ArrayList<ServiceBeandata> search(ServiceBeandata searchParameters);
```

returns an arraylist

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the 'update' attribute of the commandButton, where you can use parameters such as @all (reloads everything), @form (reloads the form) or the id of another element. Here are a few examples, I hope I understood your code correctly.

```
<h:form id="form1">

    <p:commandButton value="Update Form" action="#{fooBean.doStuff()}" update="@form" />

    <p:commandButton value="Update Table" action="#{fooBean.doStuff()}" update="table" />

    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{fooBean.list}" var="bar">
        ....
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">

    <p:commandButton value="Update table in form1" action="#{fooBean.doThings()}" update=":form1:table" />

</h:form>
```

As you can see the first button updates the whole form that is surrounding it, the second updates a specific element with the id 'table'. The third button is in a seperate form, thus it can't reach elements in form1. You have to use ':' to move out of form2, 'form1' to access components in form1 and finally :table to specifically address the table. So basically it's "go out of your form, go into this other form, update this element".

It's a bit unclear how your code looks like, please post another version with only the necessary dataTable, commandButton, dialogs and forms. Does the list really contain the objects you want after you try to load them from the database?

On a side node: your searchacc() method doesn't need to return anything, it just has to load the list from the database. You can use it as a void method instead.